# php - how to get this value from multidemnsional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$resolutions = array(
    '4:3' => array(
        '1024x768',
        '1600x1200',
        '2048x1536'
    ),
    '16:9' => array(
        '1280x720',
        '1366x768',
        '1600x900',
        '1920x1080',
        '2560x1440'
    ),
    '16:10' => array(
        '1280x800',
        '1440x900',
        '1680x1050',
        '1920x1200',
        '2560x1600'
    )
);
```

How to get 'aspect ratio', ie values: 4:3, 16:9, 16:10?

> echo $resolutions[0]

doesn't output anything

Answer (score 1):

This is an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

You can access its values like this:

```php
echo $resolutions['4:3'];
```

To get list of its keys, you can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-keys.php):

```php
$keys = array_keys($resolutions);
print_r($keys); //4:3, 16:9, 16:10
```

Finally, in order to iterate through all of its keys, you can do following:

```php
foreach ($resolutions as $aspectRatio => $resolutions)
{
     echo 'Resolution ' . $aspectRatio . ': ' . PHP_EOL;
     print_r($resolutions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = array_keys($resolutions);
echo $keys[0];
```